# Javascript localstorage messing up other code

Tags: javascript, local-storage, event-listener

I have a todo list in javascript and decided to use localstorage to save the lists. The things is the list's individual remove item buttons don't work now without clicking on the button and then pressing enter. This only happens on chrome and safari. In firefox everything works fine so I'm not sure what the issue actually is and this is my first attempt at using localstorage.

Here's the whole code base since I'm not really sure which part could be causing the issue.

```
var input = document.querySelector('input[name=todoItem]'),
btnAdd = document.querySelector('button[name=add]'),
btnClear = document.querySelector('button[name=clear]'),
btnSave = document.querySelector('button[name=save]'),
list = document.querySelector('.todo'),
storeList = [];

  list.innerHTML = window.localStorage.getItem('list');

function renderTodos(){
  //Cached array length for use in for loop
  var listLength = storeList.length,
  //Created list item and button 
  el = document.createElement('li'),
  x = document.createElement('button');

  //Set text for remove button
  x.setAttribute('class', 'remove');
  x.innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-2x"></i>';

  //Loop for adding items to array and appending items to list
  for(var i = 0; i < listLength; i++){
    el.innerHTML = storeList[i];
    list.appendChild(el);
    el.appendChild(x);
  }

  //Clear out and put focus back in input box
  input.value =  '';
  input.focus();
}

//Add todo item to list
function addTodos(e){
  //Check to see that input isn't empty or only spaces with no characters
  // and add todo item if add button is clicked or enter key is pushed
  if(input.value.trim() !== '' && (e.which ===13 || e.which ===1)){
    storeList.push(input.value);
    renderTodos();
  }
  else if(input.value.trim() === '' && (e.which ===1 || e.which === 13)){
    alert('Please Enter A Valid Item!');
    input.focus();
  }
}

function removeItem(e){
  var node = e.target;
  var attr = node.getAttribute('class');
  if(attr === 'remove'){
    node = node.parentNode;
    node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
  }
}
//Clear the whole list
function clearList(){
  // make list empty
  list.innerHTML = '';
  storeList.splice(0, storeList.length);
  renderTodos();
}

//Initialize listeners and show saved list from local storage on page load
function init(){
  btnSave.addEventListener('click', function(){
    window.localStorage.setItem('list', list.innerHTML);
  });
  list.addEventListener('click', removeItem);
  btnAdd.addEventListener('click', addTodos);
  btnClear.addEventListener('click', clearList);
  input.addEventListener('keydown', addTodos);
}
window.onload = init;
```

Everything works but the buttons with the trash can icon, which only work if clicked and then the enter key being pressed.

Comment: has nothing to do with localstorage, it has to do to you checking what was clicked. You clicked on the image so that is what the target is.

Comment: It worked fine before adding the localstorage and it works in firefox still. Why is this?

Comment: I fixed the target problem by adding another parentNode in the removeItem code. Now it works in chrome fine... But now it doesn't work in firefox. I'm guessing there is some browser difference in handling parentNode or target in this case, but I'm not sure what it is.

Comment: So check if this is "x" or if the parent is "x"

Answer (score 0):

For some reason firefox was making the target of the click the `<i>` tag while chrome and safari's target of the click was the `<button>` tag. I made a fix with a conditional for each target based on browser inconsistency.

```
<button><i></i></button>
```

Comment: You've said that all browsers use the tag. Is that what you meant?

Comment: I'm not sure what happened there sorry. I meant firefox was targeting the <i> tag and the other browsers were targeting the <button>.

Comment: How bout CSS and not unnecessarily nesting elements?

Comment: Extending the suggestion by @Phix could you try `<button style="font-style:italic;"></button>` This would give the italic text without the need for extra dom elements and should give consistent results across all browsers

Comment: The `<i>` tag is actually a font-awesome icon of a trashcan in the button. `<button><i class='fa fa-trash-o></i><button>`. I didn't mention that because I wasn't worried about that. Hope that clears that up. Thanks for the input though!